# ASP.NET - How to redirect a response with a PDF to a new tab?

Tags: asp.net, pdfsharp

I have a method which I call directly from the `Page_Load` method, to create a PDF and print it, using `PdfSharp`, which is called like this:}

```
if(IsPostBack)
     PdfSharpConvert(eventArgument, Response);
```

And the method looks like this:

```
public static void PdfSharpConvert(String html, System.Web.HttpResponse response)
{
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(790, 1800);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            XGraphics xg = XGraphics.FromGraphics(g, new XSize(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.HtmlContainer c = new TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.HtmlContainer();
            c.SetHtml(html);

            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            PdfPage page1 = new PdfPage();

... code to paint the page ...

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            pdf.Save(stream, false);
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
            response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            response.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            response.End();
}
```

This works fine, I get the PDF viewer on the browser, but I'm trying to show the PDF in a different tab in the browser, not on the same one, is there a way to do this without rewriting the views I use or doing something more complicated? I tried using `response.Redirect`, and it does redirect, but I don't know what to give it as a parameter so it properly shows the PDF in a different page.

Comment: Opening a new tab is done client-side, not server-side.  You can set a `target` attribute on a link to open in a new tab, or use `window.open` in JavaScript.  Though the use of `IsPostBack` suggests you may be relying on old WebForms controls.  It's been ages and I don't recall if they have a `target` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You require a client side javascript button.
You need to set session, or even pass the file name as part of the url.

so, say like this:

```
window.open('MyPdfViewer.aspsx', '_blank;);
```

or maybe:

```
window.open('MyPdfViewer.aspsx?FileName=' + MyFileName, '_blank;);
```

Then in the on-page load of MyPdfViewer, in the is-post back = false code stub, you place your code to pump out the pdf.

So, that 2nd new tab and web page? The on-load event of that page will have to fetch the pdf file, and push it out as you are doing now.

So pass the file name in the URL, or assume session[] has the file name to display.

You can also consider display on the current page - inside of a iFrame.